# How to Display User's Info from Database after Verifying user Exist on Yii2

Tags: database, session, activerecord, yii2

So, I have a form where users fill out their first/last names, date of birth to verify they qualify for competition. Then, if they do qualify, I want get their ID from DB and an email (prompted) and save those to a new table for pending contestant.

```
public function actionCompete()
{
    $form = new competition;

    if (isset($_POST['competition'])) {
        if ($_POST['competition']['relationship'] == 'team') {
            $form->setScenario('team');
        } elseif ($_POST['competition']['relationship'] == 'new') {
            return $this->redirect('signup');
        }

        $form->load($_POST);

        if ($form->validate()) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'You qualify!');

        }
    }

    return $this->render('apply', array('form' => $form));
}

public function validContest($attribute, $params) {
    $Contest = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('
        SELECT nm.ID
        FROM community_member
        JOIN team_member AS tm ON cm.ID_NUM = tm.ID_NUM
        WHERE nm.FIRST_NAME = :first AND (nm.id_num = :id OR nm.LAST_NAME = :last OR nm.BIRTH_NAME = :birthName) AND bm.BIRTH_DTE = :birthDate AND tm.standing IS NOT NULL AND tm.joined_yr = :memberYear
    ')->bindValues([
        ':id' => $this->Id,
        ':first' => $this->firstName,
        ':last' => $this->lastName,
        ':birthName' => $this->lastName,
        ':birthDate' => Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($this->dob, 'Y-M-d'),
        ':memberYear' => $this->qualifyYear,
    ])->queryScalar() !== false;
```

Can someone help me how to call the data an display it on view page?

Thanks,

Comment: So you want to just find the user from the one table by the data that he indicated in the form (firstname, lastname, birthdate, ...), and save it to another?

Comment: Hi FeR-S,
Yes! And get the ID so that I can save it on to another table (Either to populate on different view with a form that then save the ID and an email on a new DB).

Comment: got it, so what is the problem? Did u catch some errorrs?

Comment: I don't how. I didn't write the code but just maintaining and just learning Yii2. So I know how to display results on a _Public Function findContest()_ function. But I don't know how to display _public function validContest($attribute, $params)_. I have used **<?= $firstname['First Name'] ?>** to display results of findContest function but when I do that for the validContest, there's nothing displayed on the view page.